# How navigate to another screen

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-navigation

I have a next **RaisedButton** to go a next screen called **DetailOracion**.

Based on the example of **Flutter** to push new screen but doest work.

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Oraciones Cristianas'),
        ),
        body: SafeArea(
            child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DetailOracion()));
                },
                child: Text('Hello Wolrd'),
              )
            ],
          ),
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
```

**My DetailOracion**

```
class DetailOracion extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('Hola'),
    ),
    body: Text('Segunda Pantalla'),
  );
 }
}
```

And the error message its the next

```
I/flutter ( 3441): The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:
I/flutter ( 3441): Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator.
I/flutter ( 3441): The context used to push or pop routes from the Navigator must be that of a widget that is a
I/flutter ( 3441): descendant of a Navigator widget.
```

Comment: Can you post the code for the First screen?

Comment: @KumarBibek I add the complete code of my main.dart

Comment: your `MaterialApp` must be a parent of your custom `Widget` - now you have `MaterialApp` as a child of it (it is created inside your `Widget`'s `build()` method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When used the **MaterialPageRoute** you need to send your main class inside of **MaterialApp** from **runApp()**

Explain with Code

**Correct**

```
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
  title: 'Oraciones Cristianas',
  home: MyApp(),
));
```

You send yout first Screen insde of **MaterialApp()**, able to use **MaterialPageRoute()**

**Incorrect**

```
void main() => runApp(myApp());
```

If you simply send your first screen without **MaterialApp()** wrapper doesnt works

Answer (score 0):

Use a Builder around your button or around the Column as in the following code:

```
Builder(
    builder: (context) => RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => SelectUserType()));
          },
          child: Text('Registrese'),
        ),
  ),
```